# Wrong behavior with conditions and operators

Tags: actionscript-3, operators, conditional-statements

I've the following iteration:

```
    The content of the array respuesta is: Africa, Europa, Norteamerica
    The content of the array resultado is: Incorrect, Correct, Incorrect

    I created a Array to include both of them: 

    var contPre:Array = [ this.respuesta, this.resultado ];



    for (var a:uint = 0; a < contPre[0].length; a++){

     if (this.radioGroup1.selection.value == contPre[0][a] && 
          contPre[1][a] == "Correcto") {

        result_txt.text = "Correct";
        valor = 1;

      } else {

        result_txt.text = "Incorrect";
        valor = 0;

        }

      }


     The first time that I've executed this I found this:

     this.radioGroup1.selection.value   Obtained value: Europa
     contPre[0][a]:                     Obtained value: Europa 
     contPre[1][a]:                     Obtained value: Correcto

     The sentence go out for the second option "Incorrect".


     Somebody can explain why is this happening?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you find the correct answer, you don't break from the loop. So change:

```
if (this.radioGroup1.selection.value == contPre[0][a] && contPre[1][a] == "Correcto") {
    result_txt.text = "Correct";
    valor = 1;
}
```

into:

```
if (this.radioGroup1.selection.value == contPre[0][a] && contPre[1][a] == "Correcto") {
    result_txt.text = "Correct";
    valor = 1;
    break; // Add this line
}
```